# how to give space in navbar-Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give space to the menu, but it shows me not exact result as shown in the original template.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand simple_color" href="#">Simplex</a>
    </div> -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right w">
      <li class="active comenu"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: I am making]

[image: original template]
I want to make menu same as shown in this original template. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `navbar-nav` class with `nav-justified`.

Check out Bootstrap example on this element:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/